References Request -- Research in Computer Vision
Apologies if this is not the correct forum for this request, but I figured I'd give it a shot. I'm looking for research in computer vision on shape recognition -- any shape. Most of the computer vision/deep learning texts I've read on shape recognition teach how to discriminate between different types of pre-defined shapes (e.g., train a classifier to recognize squares versus triangles, etc.). However, it seems to me that humans can pretty easily recognize in infinite number of shapes that have no formal definition, as long as they follow the Gestalt principle of closure (See attached attached horrible MS Paint drawing).  It doesn't resemble any standard shape, but it clearly is a shape. It seems like something a Bayesian framework would incorporate well -- define a function that optimizes closure (however you might parameterize that) and then you have a generative framework for shapes. I've seen this paper on generating handwritten characters that looks loosely related to what I'm interested in, but I wanted to check for references on shapes/encoding Gestalt principles specifically. Thanks in advance.
